# Magento 2: Login as customer through rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I would like to know if its possible to get a customer token or login as a customer through the REST API in Magento 2?

I know there is a feature in admin to login as a customer, but the question is if this feature is also available from the REST API?

So basically, I have an admin user token. And with this token I would like to create a customer token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/#admin-and-customer-access-tokens), if you have the customer login credentials you can do it by calling this endpoint:

```
POST /V1/integration/customer/token

{"username":"<USER-NAME>;", "password":"<PASSWORD>"}
```

If you don’t have the credentials but wish to *impersonate* the customer through the API, you may need to develop a new endpoint which can authenticate an admin user and then use the `Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory` to create a customer token for the requested customer.